# Confusion on kubernetes OwnerRef, UID points to different resource type then kind claims, changing it breaks rancher

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I'm trying to trace down why occasionally all of our child pods will persist in kubernetes after calling a helm delete.  Note this is intermittent, usually things behave properly, we haven't determined how to reliable recreate the orphaned pods.

After some tracing of logic we thought we traced the problem to the ownerReference of the child deployment being wrong.  For the record both the child and parent are a deployment with a single replica set that points to a single running pod.

In the child deployment's ownerReference it had a uid that referenced the parent's deployment, but it had a kind of pod instead of deployment.  This seemed wrong so we changed the place where we programmatically set kind to say deployment instead of pod.  This oddly enough caused our rancher to fail, the child deployments no longer showed up in rancher at all.

edit:
after further experimentation using the correct kind leads to the deployment not showing in rancher if I go the resources->workload and use group by workload or workload/namespace options, the pods will show with the other two sorting options.  If I manually go to the appropriate URL for the deployment it will open the workload, it just isn't listed as an option in resources for some reason.

Clearly ownerReference and kind are functioning in some way differently then I had presumed, as I would have thought having a kind that was different then the resource the UID pointed to would have caused deletion failures, and I wouldn't have thought changing the kind to what I thought was the correct value would break rancher.

Can anyone explain what's going on with the ownerReference, what do the kind and the UID really mean, and should the kind match the resource type of the UID?  I've tried checking documentation but it doesn't define what the kind value really represents.

edit 2:

To answer questions in comments the child deployment is spawned by a pod from the parent deployment programaticaly using the python kubernetes API.  The parent pod creates a child deployment which in turn creates a replica set which creates a pod.  The child pods is owned by the replicaset which is owned by the deployment as expected.

The problem is the ownership of the child deployment.  We are programatically setting that replica set and currently it's being set with a UID that points to the parent deployment but a kind of pod.  As I said that doesn't seem right, but it works the majority of the times with only occasionally leaving orphaned pods; I don't even know if the odd replica set is the cause of the occasional orphaning of pods I just know it doesn't look right to me.

I tried changing the child deployment to have a kind of deployment and everything does erase correctly, but for some reason rancher refuses to show any of the child pods in the workload list.  I can get rancher to report on a pod by manually hacking the URL to point to the pod, I can even get the pod to show up if I don't group by workload.  However, it get's confused when I group by workload.

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to understand with some example manifests. For example, I would expect a Pod created by a Deployment to have an ownerReference pointing to a ReplicaSet, and that's what I see in my kubernetes environment. Are you *manually* adding owner references?

Comment: What is a child deployment? Who is the owner, how is it created?